# How to put the data using php to jquery and put in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have this code but I dont know how to fix this...

When I run this in my site and click this link

```
<a href="#add"> <img src="image/addtocart.png" width="50%" style="margin-left: 170px;"></a>
```

the data from `$row[product_name]`

will be not store in this class

```
<!----    POPUP #CHOOSE SIZE    ----->  

    <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="add"></a>

    <div class="box">
        <h2><span style="color:blue;font-weight:bold">Choose Size</span></h2>

        <?php echo "<h5>$row[product_name]</h5></br>"; ?>

    <?php
         $sql1="SELECT product_size, product_price FROM products where product_name='$row[product_name]'";

    foreach ($conn->query($sql1) as $row1){
    echo " $row1[product_price]";
    echo "<p><button name='submit' type='submit' class='a_demo_five' value='$row1[product_size]'>$row1[product_size] P$row1[product_price].00</button></p>"; 

    }
    ?>
```

This is my original code:

```
<?php
         include 'core/admin/admin_db.php';

         $sql="SELECT DISTINCT product_name, product_description, product_image FROM products WHERE product_category = 'Chicken' GROUP BY product_name";
         echo"<div class='scroll2'>";
         foreach($conn->query($sql) as $row){
         echo "<li>";
         echo "<div class='grow2 pic'><img src='$row[product_image]'></div>";
     echo "<h5>$row[product_name]</h5></br>";



  ?>


<a href="#add"> <img src="image/addtocart.png" width="50%" style="margin-left: 170px;"></a>




<!----    POPUP #CHOOSE SIZE    ----->  

<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="add"></a>

<div class="box">
    <h2><span style="color:blue;font-weight:bold">Choose Size</span></h2>

    <?php echo "<h5>$row[product_name]</h5></br>"; ?>

<?php
     $sql1="SELECT product_size, product_price FROM products where product_name='$row[product_name]'";

foreach ($conn->query($sql1) as $row1){
echo " $row1[product_price]";
echo "<p><button name='submit' type='submit' class='a_demo_five' value='$row1[product_size]'>$row1[product_size] P$row1[product_price].00</button></p>"; 

}
?>
```

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Can you please format your code right (use the preview)? This makes no sense...

Comment: Your code in the question is in a total mess.
From what I observed, you shouldn't enclose the variable in double quote, which cause $row[product_name] to be output as a string instead of variable, change it to `echo "<h5>".$row[product_name]."</h5></br>";`

Comment: Can you reformat your post please? No one likes to read code this way.

Comment: is that okay right now? sorry this my first time to use this site...

Comment: is this from 2 different php file?

Comment: nope... I just use id's so I can link them..

Comment: I can't see `foreach($conn->query($sql) as $row){` closing anywhere.

Comment: when I click the link of #add and go to `<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="add"></a>

<div class="box">
    <h2><span style="color:blue;font-weight:bold">Choose Size</span></h2>

    <?php echo "<h5>$row[product_name]</h5></br>"; ?>` the first array of $row[product_name] will post it... the other data cannot..

Comment: should I use Jquery for getting the data when I click the add to cart button?

Comment: No, php and sql fit better in this case. If you retrieve data from json or xml or something like that, then it's probably better to use jquery. Or better.. Easier atleast.

Comment: jquery allow data exchange without reloading the page, if you use pure php and sql, then everytime you add an item to cart, your page will be refresh which is not going to be good for long run, so what I would suggest is use jquery to get data from database

Comment: @Woody still not working... when I put this code: ` $sql1="SELECT product_size, product_price FROM products where product_name='".$row['product_name']."'"; foreach ($conn->query($sql1) as $row1){ echo "<p><button name='submit' type='submit' class='a_demo_five' value='".$row1['product_size']."'>".$row1['product_size']." P".$row1['product_price'].".00</button></p>"; } ` out in the <div class="box"> it will work... multiple data will see but when it is inside... only the first product name will be revealed... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not enclose variable in double quote as they are meant for string. You are also missing out some closing bracket which make the whole code not functioning.

Note that you must use different id for different item, or else page will only load the first class when you click add.

```
<?php
include 'core/admin/admin_db.php';
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT product_name, product_description, product_image FROM products WHERE product_category = 'Chicken' GROUP BY product_name";
echo "<div class='scroll2'>";
foreach($conn->query($sql) as $row){
    $product_name = $row['product_name'];
    echo "<li>";
    echo "<div class='grow2 pic'><img src='".$row['product_image']."'></div>";
    echo "<h5>".$product_name."</h5>";
    echo "<a href='#add_".$row['product_id']."'><img src='image/addtocart.png' style='width:50%;margin-left:170px;'></a>";
    // POPUP #CHOOSE SIZE
    echo "<a href='#x' class='overlay' id='add_".$row["product_id"]."'></a>";
    echo "<div class='box'>";
    echo "<h2><span style='color:blue;font-weight:bold'>Choose Size</span></h2>";
    echo "<h5>".$product_name."</h5>"; 
    $sql1="SELECT product_size, product_price FROM products WHERE product_name='$product_name'";
    foreach ($conn->query($sql1) as $row1){
        echo $row1['product_price'];
        echo "<p><button name='submit' type='submit' class='a_demo_five' value='".$row1['product_size']."'>".$row1['product_size']." P".$row1['product_price'].".00</button></p>"; 
    }
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</li>";
}
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: I think it's better to use single quotes in array keys like `$row1['product_price']`.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I missed out that one though...

Comment: Thanks @Woody :) but why happens when I click the link of #add and go to <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="add"></a> <div class="box"> <h2><span style="color:blue;font-weight:bold">Choose Size</span></h2> <?php echo "<h5>$row[product_name]</h5></br>"; ?> the first array of $row[product_name] will post it... the other data array cannot..

Comment: I think the first loop should close after the last loop. So replace `}` to the end. Before `?>` ofcourse. Now there is only 1 add to cart button for several products.

Comment: I edited the code as I just realize you are not closing all the `<div>` and `<li>`

Comment: I think I have to reorder the code to work properly, the sequence doesn't looks right to me

Comment: @jardieSalas updated the code, please try and see if this works well

Comment: still not working... when I put this code: `
    $sql1="SELECT product_size, product_price FROM products where product_name='".$row['product_name']."'";
    foreach ($conn->query($sql1) as $row1){
        echo "<p><button name='submit' type='submit' class='a_demo_five' value='".$row1['product_size']."'>".$row1['product_size']." P".$row1['product_price'].".00</button></p>"; 
    }  ` out in the <div class="box"> it will work... multiple data will see but when it is inside... only the first product name will be revealed... :/

Comment: updated some missed out syntax and closing, try again with new edited code. And what do you mean by first product name will be revealed?

Comment: @Woody $row[product_name] has many data... and the value of the button should have different sizes like grande, solo, regular, and etc. but the grande will only revealed in the value of the button and not the others... 

I think when I click the add to cart button it should have jquery for the selected <li> but I dont know how to do it. I am lack of ideas right now... and my brain drained T_T

you can check the site so you can try: [link](http://migrandegensan.com)

Comment: do you have a unique id for each size of each product?

Comment: yes.... I have tables separately... the products, product_category, and product_size... and all of them have foreign keys

Comment: i know what is the problem, it is the id, you have to specify different id for different product, let me adjust the code again

Comment: updated, please adjust `product_id` to the primary key in your database as I do not know your db entry, this is working and i tested on your website

Comment: you visit the site... migrandegensan.com so you really see what it looks like... and still I have many things to fix in that site...

Comment: try your best, previously I was also a self learnt php programmer, and it took me some time to get a full php website done, don't worry, people here will help you out

Comment: please change the `product_id` to your db primary key or you will get error

Comment: OMG! IT WORKED! THANK YOU SO MUCH @Woody !!!!!! You're so great! :*

Comment: I saw it working too, so you did it. Well done. =)

Comment: You are my hero sir!!! Salute to you! I've been thinking these how many hours.. and you fix it in a minute! I could kiss you right now...

Comment: Because I just fixed a same someone problem few days ago, and when I visited your website I know it. =) 3am here, I got to sleep, let me know if you have another issue. Will help as soon as I have time.

Comment: Okay sir! Thank you so much again! I will tap you if I have another problem... gosh! your so amazing!